# opencv - cropping handwritten lines (line segmentation)

Tags: python, opencv, text-segmentation, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to build a handwriting recognition system using python and opencv.
The recognition of the characters is not the problem but the segmentation.
I have successfully :

- segmented a word into single characters
- segmented a **single sentence** into words in the required order.

But I couldn't segment different lines in the document. I tried sorting the contours (to avoid line segmentation and use only word segmentation) but it didnt work.
I have used the following code to segment words contained in a handwritten document , but it returns the words out-of-order(it returns words in left-to-right sorted manner) :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import image
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('orig',image)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

#grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#binary
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('second',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#dilation
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('dilated',img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#find contours
im2,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # show ROI
    cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(90,0,255),2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('marked areas',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Please note that i am able to segment all the words here **but they appear out order.Is there any way to sort these contours in order of top to bottom**

**OR**

**segment the image into separate lines so that each line can be segmented into words using above code?**

Comment: why don't you sort it by x and y then?

Comment: Actually i tried that but it just results in complete reordering of contours again. it doesnt return the contours in the correct order.
I did left-to-right sorting followed by top-down sorting ,but contours are out of order. So i think each line would need to be separated.

Comment: Making a list sorting contours based on x,y is the easiest i'd say. Add an image is you can.

Comment: @SidharthRamesh hi there. Do you have any contact (WA, Telegram ) ?

Comment: @Link you could email me at sidharthr44@gmail.com

Comment: @SidharthRamesh How did separate word into single characters? Are there any references?

Comment: @VishnuJayanand I updated the answer addressing your query,

Comment: @SidharthRamesh Does reducing iterations work for separating handwritten characters? Also, how do you deal with text of different font sizes?

Comment: @VishnuJayanand I dont understand your doubt on reducing iterations. This code will work for different font sizes because the cropped region for a line is calculated based on the largest character in that line. You can check the code with images having varying sized text.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the required segmentation by making a change to the above code on the line:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
```

I changed it to :

```
kernel = np.ones((5,100), np.uint8)
```

Now i get the outputs as following[image: segmented lines of input text]
This also works with handwritten text images with lines that are not perfectly horizontal:

**EDIT :**
For getting individual characters out of a word, do the following :

1. Resize the contour containing the word using the code as follows.

   ```
   im = cv2.resize(image,None,fx=4, fy=4, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
   ```
2. Apply same contour detection process as in line segmentation, but with a kernel of size (5,5), i.e :

   ```
   kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
   img_dilation = cv2.dilate(im_th, kernel, iterations=1)
   ```

Comment: Can you describe how to crop each bounding line into separate image. Any idea or resource. Your answer is helpful

Comment: @Sushant you mean saving each of the cropped contours into separate images ? 
just save each of the detected contours as an image. thats it.