# Perform line segmentation (cropping) serially with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, text-segmentation, handwriting-recognition

I am performing full Page Offline Handwriting Recognition with Deep Learning.

The main idea is to build the model that can take one line of text image and give it's corresponding text. For this main task is do line segmentation of every line in a page and send it to the model.

But, i apply this code below by slightly modification seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282691/opencv-cropping-handwritten-lines-line-segmentation). The main problem comes here is that it crop the line of the image randomly and i save it serially as segment_no_1,2,3....

When i pass such segmented lines (randomly) to the model then it can not produce serial corresponding digital text.

Is there suitable method or algorithm to perform line segmentation with OpenCV serially as in Original Image. I have already found the line segmentation with deep learning but i not want to use that.

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import image
image = cv2.imread('input2.png')
#cv2.imshow('orig',image)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

#grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#binary
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('second',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#dilation
kernel = np.ones((5,100), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('dilated',img_dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#find contours
im2,ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#sort contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])

for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # show ROI
    cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
    cv2.imwrite("segment_no_"+str(i)+".png",roi)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),( x + w, y + h ),(90,0,255),2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('final_bounded_box_image.png',image)
cv2.imshow('marked areas',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: The final output of the code on IAM database form]

The `segment_no_1.png` as first line segment can be found from middle or sometimes second last and so on.

So, what modification should need to find segmented lines correct order (serially) as in original image.

Any improvement on my code is also highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u try something like histogram appoarch? Also line segmentation is not an easy task. For the best accuracy. I suggest using RCNN or UNET, .... that work at pixel level.

Comment: But i am engage on line segmentation with openCV without deep learning performing thresholding.

Comment: There are a bunch of online repo on Github for line segmentation. I guess you should do a search.

Comment: Solution i found about it here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should follow [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/20/sorting-contours-using-python-and-opencv/) where show that Sorting Contours using Python and OpenCV.

The basic steps that I follow are:

1. Blur the image and if necessary convert to gray scale first.
2. Apply the Canny edge detection algorithm to find the outline of every character.
3. Pass the edge detected image to the Adaptive Algorithm which works better considering the neighbouring points.
4. Perform dilation which performs better on line segmentation.
5. Perform the line segmentation on the copy of dilated image which produces the segments randomly.
6. Finally sort the segment in a order "Top to bottom".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send all the sorted (assuming sorting means: top-left to bottom-right) cropped-images of the input image given by the cv2.findContours() to the recognition model, you do not need to pass the ctrs through the sorted function. cv2.findContours() gives all the ctrs in bottom-right to top-left order. Just reverse it using reversed function or you can loop over all the ctrs in a reverse way. After this, use cv2.boundingrect() followed cropping with python slicing and save it in a list. Finally, send the list to the recognition model to recognition line-by-line.
[image]