# Using find-contours in line, word, and character segmentation for OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-segmentation

I am working on a handwritten character recognition system. I have done the preprocessing and line segmentation stage successfully. I have used this [opencv - cropping handwritten lines (line segmentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282691/opencv-cropping-handwritten-lines-line-segmentation) for line segmentation which uses findContours for line segmentation. Is this a valid or recommended way of implementing segmentation for OCR

Comment: You have to provide us with more informations. And don't reference the title in the body of the question. If needed, write the text again.

Comment: Hi.

Please provide some additional information like files you are workig on (the images) and what you did until now (the code).

Tip: segmenting handwritten text is not so easy.